# How do I override git pushRemote?

Tags: git

I have a Git repo with a branch `my_branch`, and a remote `origin` with a branch of the same name. When on `my_branch`, `git push origin my_branch` works as expected, but `git push` returns

```
fatal: 'my_branch' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Looking at [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) and [this blog post](https://longair.net/blog/2011/02/27/an-asymmetry-between-git-pull-and-git-push/), it wasn't clear to me why this wouldn't work. I suspect that the reason might be this line in my `.git/config`:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/user/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    pushurl = https://github.com/user/repo.git
[branch "other"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
    pushRemote = origin
[branch "my_branch"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/my_branch
    pushRemote = my_branch     <------
```

Am I correct in thinking that Git is looking for a *remote* named `my_branch`? If so, how can I override/remove this?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchltnamegtpushRemote – Sounds like you don’t want that. You can just delete those lines in the gitconfig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I correct in thinking that Git is looking for a *remote* named `my_branch`?

Yes, [the documentation for that option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchltnamegtpushRemote) says:

> When on branch `<name>`, it overrides `branch.<name>.remote` for pushing.

More helpfully, [the documentation for `branch.<name>.remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchltnamegtremote) says:

> When on branch `<name>`, it tells `git fetch` and `git push` which remote to fetch from/push to.

So yes, this setting should specify a *remote name*, not a *branch name*.

> If so, how can I override/remove this?

Most simply, edit that file. You can change the value of that setting to `origin`, or since you want it to be the same as the `remote` setting for the same branch, you can simply delete the `pushRemote` line altogether.

You can also use [the `git config` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) which will edit the file for you if you're worried about messing up the format.

Comment: Well, `git config` does the editing in the "right way", which for some beginners is sometimes a bit of a challenge. I personally think that learning how to edit the file is worthwhile myself, but there are those who recommend always using `git config` to do it.

Comment: @torek I can see that reasoning. Personally, I find the arguments to `git config` much more confusing than the text file format, but people's experiences vary. I've re-worded that last sentence a bit.